# Regular expression in Delphi for all matching lines in a StringList

Tags: regex, delphi

I'm building a component with custom autocomplete feature but turns out it becomes too slow sometimes... I'm not sure why but I bet is because the loop I do in the code.

To avoid looping I was trying to figure out how to use regular expression in the whole TStringList at once but I had no success, I'm not sure what classes to use or how to properly mount the expression itself

Could someone help me to convert this piece of code?

FHookTo is a ComboBox and the current expression is ^(?=.*NOTIFICAÇÃO.*).*$

```
if (FHookTo.Text <> '') then
begin
  for i := 0 to FStoredItems.Count-1 do
  begin
    if TRegEx.IsMatch(FStoredItems[I], Expression, [roIgnoreCase]) then
      FHookTo.Items.Add(FStoredItems[I]);
  end;
end
```

Comment: If your goal is optimal performance, regex isn't the way to go.

Comment: Are you adding several items? Perhaps you simply forgot to use `BeginUpdate` and `EndUpdate`. That has a huge effect on performance.

Comment: wanted to give a try to check if the problem would persist if I could do it in one single time without the loop

Comment: First try adding `BeginUpdate` and `EndUpdate` (IMPORTANT: protected by `try..finally`). I really suspect that will make it *much* faster.

Comment: Yes I use BeginUpdate and EndUpdate

Comment: Good. I would be very interested in seeing your `for` loop solution.

Comment: It is in the piece of code I posted, I do an check for TRegEx.IsMatch for each line and add the result to another StringList, was strugling to achieve that with the multiline stuff

Comment: Ah, then I understand. Well, as I said, a regex isn't the fastest option. A manual test is typically faster. But I still think it is strange that it takes so long, if you are using `BeginUpdate` and `EndUpdate`. How many items are there?

Comment: Well, converting the string list to a single string, doing a regex on that one, and then converting back to a string list is going to be even slower.

Comment: There are about 20.000 lines to search. I build a expression with the words I'm looking for and look for matches line by line... Don't know exactly how to do it in one single shot. Thought I would use the DelimitedText property of the StringList to use it as one single string

Comment: I'd abandon regex altogether. `Dest.BeginUpdate; try for i := 0 to Source.Count - 1 do if Mathces(Source[i]) then Dest.Add(Source[i]); finally Dest.EndUpdate end;` with an efficiently implemented `Matches` function.

Comment: That's going to be *significantly* slower, I think. Then you have to build and search one huge string. `for` loops are extremely fast, you know. Doing one million iterations takes no (human) measurable time.

Comment: Try `var
  i, c: Integer;
begin
  c := 1;
  for i := 1 to 100000000 do
  begin
    if not Odd(c) then
      c := c div 2
    else
      c := 3*c+1
  end;` It will have completed its 100 million iterations before you even notice it has begun!

Comment: could You clarify a little more about the use of Matches you mentioned?

Comment: That's a function you implement yourself: `function Matches(const A: string): Boolean`

Comment: I could give you an example as an answer, but I don't speak regex. Could you please describe in words what the regex `^(?=.NOTIFICAÇÃO.).*$` means?

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand You don't know regex but you know [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collatz_conjecture) obviously ;-)

Comment: I don't know if `TRegEx.IsMatch()` caches the regex; if it doesn't, it's highly inefficient.

Comment: I'm delighted someone recognised Collatz! :)

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand "*Perhaps you simply forgot to use `BeginUpdate` and `EndUpdate`. That has a huge effect on performance*" - it has a huge effect for `TStrings` descendants that are directly tied to the UI, etc. But for a plain `TStringList` there is no effect at all, unless you have `OnChanging`/`OnChange` event handler(s) assigned to it.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: True. But the OP wrote "FHookTo is a ComboBox". (So my example with `Source` and `Dest` isn't optimal, I guess. Should have use `Dest.Items`)

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand "*FHookTo is a ComboBox*" - good catch, I missed that. OK, in that case, one optimization would be to add strings to a `TStringList` first, and then `Assign()` that to `FHookTo` when done.

Comment: "custom autocomplete feature"... Quit after 20 matches - there's no point in providing more suggestions at once. Also there lacks any sense for the ending part `.*$` (and probably other parts in your regex).

Answer (score 5):

The source for `TRegEx.IsMatch(const Input, Pattern: string; Options: TRegExOptions)` shows that a `TRegEx` is created at every invocation (which is a costly operation):

```
class function TRegEx.IsMatch(const Input, Pattern: string; Options: TRegExOptions): Boolean;
var
  LRegEx: TRegEx;
  Match: TMatch;
begin
  LRegEx := TRegEx.Create(Pattern, Options);
  Match := LRegEx.Match(Input);
  Result := Match.Success;
end;
```

Since you call it a large number of times, it's highly inefficient. You should create a single `TRegEx` and reuse it.

This unoptimized example takes about 2500 ms:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  i: integer;
  t1, t2: cardinal;
begin
  t1 := GetTickCount;
  for i := 1 to 100000 do
    TRegex.IsMatch('abcdef', 'cd', [roIgnoreCase]);
  t2 := GetTickCount;
  ShowMessage(IntToStr(t2-t1));
end;
```

This optimized example (single `TRegEx`) takes about 31 ms:

```
procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  i: integer;
  t1, t2: cardinal;
  LRegEx: TRegEx;
begin
  t1 := GetTickCount;
  LRegEx := TRegEx.Create('cd', [roIgnoreCase]);
  for i := 1 to 100000 do
    LRegEx.IsMatch('abcdef');
  t2 := GetTickCount;
  ShowMessage(IntToStr(t2-t1));
end;
```

Comment: That's a huge difference. And I suspect you can reduce it to maybe a third or so by skipping regex altogether and using a specialised matching function. But the OP almost certainly doesn't need any better performance than your second example.